# Proving that mean KDR in a videogame is one

Tags: summation, proof-writing, average, ratio

This is not related to schoolwork. A friend of mine challenged me to prove that the mean KDR (assuming players can only die at the hands of other players) must always be equal to one. I have gotten through the logic part, and am now faced with the math part (which I am less capable of doing), and would like some help.

My logic is as follows: Every kill event is also a death event, and every death event is also a kill event. Therefore, the total number of kills must always equal the number of deaths. We know then that TOTAL kdr = 1. For a more explicit expression of this, we can represent the game as a directed graph whose nodes are players and whose edges represent kills. In such a graph, the in-degree of a node is its deaths and its out-degree is its kills.

I don't think that will be necessary. Instead I'm just sticking with that kills and deaths are distributed a certain way among players, and that each player's kdr = kills/deaths for that player. Proving what I have written in the following picture should finalize the whole proof. If it isn't possible to prove this, maybe the graph abstraction will help us.

EDIT: Forgot to mention earlier that if a player has 0 deaths, the denominator of their KDR is 1, not 0 (to prevent infinite KDR, widely used in games).

[image]

Comment: what is this KDR?

Comment: Kill-death ratio, it is common in shooter games.

Comment: Do you wish to know the behavior of the K/D ratio for *all players* in a match, or the mean of *individual* K/D ratios?

Comment: Nevermind, I see now you addressed that. For some reason I couldn't read that paragraph without a refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true: 
consider for example $2$ players $A$ and $B$, $A$ kills $B$ once, $B$ kills $A$ $m>1$ times, then we have:

$$\frac{m+\frac{1}{m}}{2}\not=1$$

Comment: Oh gosh. Perhaps we could prove whether it approaches 1 or not?

Comment: Actually it approaches $\infty$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ @MilesRufat-Latre

Comment: well darn! I guess I was emotionally invested in a certain outcome.

Comment: A more interesting question is whether it approaches one as you add more players.

Comment: That is also false since we can make one of the players a death-pool and make all the other players kill him, increasing their kill death arbitarily

Comment: there is one important detail I missed: players with 0 deaths are calculated as if with 1 death for kdr purposes

Comment: That's very existentialist.

Comment: "You have survived this match, but it is meaningless to do so. Your mortality awaits, irrespective of whether you sniped that bro on the rooftop."

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly false,if there are two player: Alice and Bob and Bob kills alice 20 times and Bob kills alice once then Alice's ratio will be $\frac{1}{20}$ and Bob's ratio will be $\frac{20}{1}$, the mean of these two ratio's is $\frac{401}{40}>20$

---

Construction to increase mean kdr arbitrarily for any number of players:

Pick 1 player $v$ and make him kill all other players once. Then make all other players kill $v$ $k$ times. What is the sum of all the kdr now?

$\underbrace{\frac{n-1}{(n-1)k}}_{\text{player v}}+\underbrace{(n-1)\frac{k}{1}}_\text{the other n-1 players}\geq(n-1)k$.

So the arithmetic mean of the kdr's is at least $\frac{(n-1)k}{n}$. Increasing $k$ arbitrarily increases the kdr mean arbitrarily.

Comment: The OP says nothing about K/D for players *individually.*

Comment: He says the mean KDR, I think he means the arithmetic mean of all of the Kill death ratios.

Comment: Yes, but does that mean KDR among players, or KDR among matches? In either case, I couldn't see the paragraph where he addressed that, so I think it's probably KDR among players within a single match.

Comment: Well, in either case it is false.

Comment: actually, if we're talking about the total KDR for the entire game, it's always 1. I'm talking about the mean of individual kdrs.

Comment: I know, that is what the answer addresses, clearly the total kdr is 1 since in any digraph the sum of in degrees is equal to the sum of out-degrees.